# c++ FEM libraries that implement 3D elastic membrane elements

Tags: finite-element-analysis

I need to incorporate a structural FEM solver in to my C++ code base.

Specifically, I am solving a 3D surface mesh problem, and I need a 3D elastic membrane element, whose is parameterized by thickness and structural material properties.
If possible I would like to use a free open-source solution, and works on windows.

I have not managed to find support for this in the libraries I am familiar with (MFEM, VEGA) , and I am not sure about fenics-shells as all the examples use thick plates and 2D meshes, and there is no mention of elastic membranes.

Any recommendations of libraries for this problem?

thanks.

Comment: My guess is that your problem is more complex than you know.  I'm imagining a 3D elastic membrane that is not planar.  You dismiss thick plates/shells, but make no mention of what your expectation is for out of plane behavior.  This is likely to be a large deformation/large rotation non-linear problem - more like fabric than a shell.

Comment: Hi duffymo, thanks for the reply.
Perhaps I wasn't clear, In terms of out of plane behavior, I was looking for a thin plate model, specifically (kirchhoff-love). I settled on using abaqus with python scripting to automatically generate the fem results, which I then read back to my C++ code.